# Hibernate query with Criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria, criteria-api

Anyone please help me to convert the following SQL query to Hibernate:

```
Select * 
  from(select to_char(start_time, 'dd/mm/yyyy HH') st, 
             sum(success_count) 
         from GMO_DETAILS 
        where start_time between ? and ? 
        group by to_char(start_time, 'dd/mm/yyyy HH')
        order by sum(success_count) desc )
where rownum<=10
```

I tried with lots of options but none is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to convert it into hql you can use your sql with `SQLQuery` class.

here is an example

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(yourSql);
query.addEntity("_this", YoutEntityCalss.class);
query.list();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.
But we are moving out of SQL dependency, we are not using anything related with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Criteria API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria), meaning:

- [mapping the model entities](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html)
- the `rownum` ([pagination](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-querying-executing)) can be achieved with the `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResults`
- for `sum` use [projections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-projection)
- to add `where` clauses you should [Restrictions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-narrowing)

This is basically a tip to read the [manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/).

Hope it isn't too vague but without any specific model mapping this is as far as I can go.